# Starting Help First Android app with c#

Tags: c#, android, websocket

I'm trying to write an android app using VS Community 2015 in c#
The App should send a message to a websocket an display it received answer.

This is my MainActivity.cs

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.MyButton);
        TextView t1 = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textView1);

        button.Click += delegate
        {
            string msg = SetStatusText();
            t1.SetText(msg,TextView.BufferType.Normal);
        };

    }

    private string SetStatusText()
    {
        Connector c = new Connector();
        c.Connect();
        return c.msg;

    }
}
```

The Connector goes like this

```
class Connector
{
    public string msg { get; set; }

    WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.103:2012/");
    public void Connect()
    {
        websocket.Opened += new EventHandler(websocket_Opened);
        websocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(websocket_MessageReceived);
        websocket.Open();
    }

    private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        msg = e.Message;
    }

    private void websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        websocket.Send("Status");
    }   


}
```

In debug mode I see the message the websocket returned in msg variable of the Connector, but the way I'm returning it to the MainActivity doesn't work. It stays NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the "msg" variable just after connecting to the WebSocket, that will fail as you still did not received a message, you need to wait in some way to websocket_MessageReceived be executed.

If you want to wait until the message is received you can use an event:

```
class Connector
{
    public string msg { get; set; }
    public event EventHandler MessageReceived;

    WebSocket websocket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.1.103:2012/");
    public void Connect()
    {
        websocket.Opened += new EventHandler(websocket_Opened);
        websocket.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(websocket_MessageReceived);
        websocket.Open();
    }

    private void websocket_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        msg = e.Message;
        if(MessageReceived != null)
            MessageReceived(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private void websocket_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        websocket.Send("Status");
    }   
}
```

Then, when you create your connection you can do:

```
c.MessageReceived += (o,e) => t1.SetText(c.msg,TextView.BufferType.Normal);
```

Comment: No that works I see the variable filled, If the socket is opened the message "Status" is send and the message received event is fired and msg is set.

Comment: No, it doesn't, you see it when debugging because you set a breakpoint giving enough time for the server to send a message, when you don't set a breakpoint there is not enough time and it doesn't arrive before you try to use it.

Comment: If you want a proof of it, convert your function to async, and after c.Connect() add await Task.Delay(5000), then it will work BUT, don't use that for production as the interval between conection and message is variable.

Comment: Ok , I will Test it.  Or is there another way to inplement this?  Maybe the Connector Class could update the textview at the received Event?

Comment: That would be the right approach, you can use a callback or expose an event handler on the Connector class.

Comment: Do you have an example (I m really New to android devel)

Comment: That's not android, it's basic C#, let me write an example.

Comment: Thanks, the connector class is modified, Then I tried this             button.Click += delegate
            {
               
                Connector c = new Connector();
                c.Connect();
                c.MessageReceived += (o, e) => t1.SetText(msg, TextView.BufferType.Normal);
            }; on the mainactivity but msg is not available in the context.

Comment: I forgot to add "c.", updated answer, also, hook to the event before calling Connect.